# package for \mathbb{lowercase letter} symbol

Tags: symbols, packages, amsfonts

I wonder if there is any package that produces a  `\mathbb{}` symbol for lowercase letters.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Voting to reopen because closing it as a duplicate of the deTeXify question is no help to anyone. It just means everyone coming here will follow the link only to discover it's not a specific answer to this question at all. Incidentally, deTeXify would not recognise my hand drawn lowercase mathbb letters, despite my best efforts.

Comment: Also, while both of the existing answers work, neither is a very nice font, so it would be quite helpful if this question would accept new answers.

Answer (score 11):

After a little searching on the internet, I found the `bbm` package that produces the blackboard symbol for lowercase letter

Answer (score 7):

You can use `mathbbol` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathbbol}

\begin{document}

\[ \mathbb{abcd} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well, they show some likeness with black board letters but I would not use them. I find those letters awkward. Especially the upper case letters are awful. The answer itself is syntactically ok.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I agree with you. Nothing like amsfonts :)

Comment: The blackboard bold alphabets are described in table 213 of the Comprehensive list cited in the accepted answer.