# Lower case \mathbb with a decent font

Tags: math-fonts

In the answers to [package for \mathbb{lowercase letter} symbol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254445/package-for-mathbblowercase-letter-symbol#comment1690699_254445) there are two options for a blackboard bold font that includes lower case letters. They look like this:

[image]

Unfortunately neither of these look very good to me. The mathbol one is better, but still looks pretty awkward, with the `n` being much wider than the `s`, for example.

On the other hand, MathJax has quite a nice font for this - if I write the same thing on a Stack Exchange site that supports it, I get this:

[image]

I know that MathJax isn't LaTeX, but since the font exists I'm wondering if there is a LaTeX package that provides it, or something similar. I wouldn't use the mathbol or bbm fonts in a paper, but I would use this if there was a way to generate it in LaTeX.

Here's the mwe for the two LaTeX packages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathbbol}
\usepackage{bbm}
\begin{document}

mathbol package: $\mathbb{Lens}$

bbm package: $\mathbbm{Lens}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it an option to use LuaTeX and to load one of the many OpenType fonts that have these lower case double struck letters?

Comment: @mickep unfortunately I'd run into the age-old issue that arXiv doesn't support LuaTeX. I really wish they did.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The only font I know which isn't really ugly is STIX2-bb.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{stix2bb}{\skewchar\font127 }
\DeclareFontShape{U}{stix2bb}{m}{n} {<-> stix2-mathbb}{}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbb}{U}{stix2bb}{m}{n}

\begin{document}

$X+\mathbb{X}$

$\mathbb{AbcdeFghi}$

\end{document}
```

Don't try anything else than letters inside `\mathbb`.

[image]

Comment: Cool, I'm pretty sure that's exactly the font MathJax uses.

Comment: @N.Virgo -- The blackboard bold in STIX2 was modeled after the old metal Monotype alphabet.  Not everybody really likes it, but it's definitely "traditional".  (Just a historical aside.)